# A PEMDAS issue request for explanation

Tags: algebra, arithmetic-operations

This question made the rounds recently -

$8÷2(2+2)=?$

Now, I glanced at this, answered "1" and then saw the full article printed in the New York Times, [The Math Equation That Tried to Stump the Internet](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/02/science/math-equation-pedmas-bemdas-bedmas.html).

The article concludes that 16 is the correct answer, citing that

$8÷2×4$

when approached from left to right, results in 16.

My disagreement lies in the dismissal of the parentheses, as my explanation would be that

$8÷2(x+x)$ would, as a first step, simplify to

$8÷2(2x)$ and then

$8÷4x$

in which case, if I were to offer this last bit and asked for a value when x=2, few would argue that division comes first.

Now, my question - for those who agree with me, what is it about PEMDAS that misses this issue, that the number right before the parentheses multiplies the contents with a higher priority than the division to its left? How do we address that priority?

(If you agree with the articles' '16', I am happy to hear the reasoning.)

The third option is also fine, that such a set of numbers and symbols is ambiguous, and a second set of parentheses is required for clarification.

Note: PEMDAS is an acronym for the words parenthesis, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction. I don’t know how common it is outside the US. Or even in different locations within the US, for that matter.

Comment: This is where I lose you: "$8÷2(2x)$ and then $8÷4x$." Why do you prioritize evaluating $2(2x)$ before $8÷2$, which has L-to-R priority?

Comment: For a reason I struggle to articulate, it seems to me the multiplying of what’s in parentheses should take priority to the division.

Comment: You are missing option #4: bad typography and shoddy proof-reading. Something like this should simply never be encountered, period.

Comment: I agree with @JörgWMittag  You should never see this and you should never write this.  If you do see it, you may assume it was written by people who do not know what they are doing.

Comment: please also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313038/what-is-the-reason-for-the-left-to-right-rule, and in particular Bill Dubuque's answer (which I wrote based on his comment to keep a trace): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3313474/96639. The linked article is excellent to answer this question.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: To me, it's because 8÷f(2x) surely doesn't mean (8/f)(2x), so I apply the same priority to 8%2(2x).

Comment: On my blog (2013); you'll an analog of this problem appearing in the comments. [Are Parentheses Multiplication?](http://www.madmath.com/2013/10/are-parentheses-multiplication.html)

Comment: The problem is that the obelus (÷) is completely useless as an element in the mathematical language for formulating expressions.  It stands in for division with children who are too young to yet understand fractions.  Once you move beyond two simple operands it becomes entirely subject to interpretation.  Real mathematicians never use it.  Ever.  At all.

Comment: In addition to excellent Daniel's answer, I would like to note that there is *no such thing as implied multiplication* in mathematics. All there is, is an *implied multiplication **sign***. If in doubt, put the implicit sign in the equation explicity and confusion vanishes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the expression were, say, $48\div 4\times 12$, there would not be much disagreement (multiplication and division are performed from left to right).

[image: 48dvt12]

But an expression such as $48\div 4(12)$ results in disagreement because the parentheses could mean one of two different things:  a way of grouping or a way of multiplying.

[image: 48d4p12]

If one interprets the parentheses as a set of grouping symbols, then the "P" in "PEMDAS" is used and the "correct" answer is $1$.  If one interprets the parentheses as a multiplication, then the "M" in "PEMDAS" is used and the "correct" answer is $144$.

As far as I know, there is no "authority" that declares which of these two interpretations is correct.  As you can see from the images above, even engineers working in the same calculator company do not seem to have a common interpretation.

Comment: "that declares which of these two interpretations is correct." This is clear in a programming context, because the operator precedence must be unambiguous: the parentheses are never ambiguous. Maybe the programming language precedences are seeping into clarify the mathematics issues?

Comment: At the P stage of PEMDAS, it is the expression inside the parentheses that is evaluated. Parentheses have no effect outside of them. In "4(12)", there are both parentheses and an implicit multiplication. The evaluation is done as follows:

Comment: (0) 48/4(12);
(1) P: 48/4*12;
(2) D: 12*12;
(3) M: 144.

Comment: Like @Jake, I can't imagine that the "grouping" function could coherently entail anything outside the parentheses; that's madness. IMO the real question is whether parentheses are multiplication; my answer is "no", that's also crazy. It's the *juxtaposition* (whether parentheses or not) that makes the multiplication and gives the product 144. http://www.madmath.com/2013/10/are-parentheses-multiplication.html

Comment: @DanielR.Collins in $f(x)$, f and x are linked together even though f is outside the parentheses. Is that madness?

Comment: @EricDuminil: It's certainly not multiplication. Nor any elementary operation under discussion. Your suggestion further down that it should come after exponents is definitely madness.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: All your arguments make sense and seem correct. My last line of defense would be a warning : if there's an ambiguity and your position is "I'm correct and you're mad", you'll not interpret correctly what the author meant, even if you're technically correct. E.g. with $1/2\pi$.

Answer (score 20):

The issue is the implied multiplication in 8÷2(2). Different calculators actually resolve this differently, so in that sense we would want to say this is ambiguous.

If implied multiplication works the same way explicit multiplication does, then we do the division first (left to right) and get 4(2). If implicit multiplication has a higher priority than explicit operations, we would get what you want: 8÷4.

I hate these examples, because they lead people to think math is very silly. The conventions (of PEMDAS) are usually reflected in the typesetting conventions we use. You would never see someone using the ÷ symbol in a complicated expression like this. It would be written 8/2(2+2), and then it would feel right to do the division first. (I believe our subconscious has internalized PEMDAS as matching the typesetting, loose for + and -, and tighter for multiplication and division, and even tighter for exponentiation.)

Back to your 8÷4. If we write it as 8/4, can you see the ambiguity? Is that x on the top or bottom of the fraction?

Comment: Thank-you. Yes, this - "I hate these examples, because they lead people to think math is very silly." Which is the issue with many Common Core examples taken out of context. To be fair, the Times author did note "No professional mathematician would ever write something so obviously ambiguous."

Comment: Just curious: why should 8÷2(2) be any different than 8/2(2+2)?

Comment: I don't think anyone thinks it should be. I think @JoeTaxpayer thought it would clarify why his way of thinking seemed sensible.

Comment: _"It would be written 8/2(2+2), and then it would feel right to do the division first"_ - er, I'd say the opposite.  Specifically, when I see $1/2x$ it _always_ means $\frac{1}{2x}$, not $\frac{1}{2}x$

Comment: There is no such thing as "implied multiplication" in mathematics. All there is, is an implied multiplication **sign** in mathematical notation. If in doubt, put the implicit sign in the equation *explicity* and confusion vanishes.

Comment: Interpreting 1/2x as (1/2)x would imply that a fraction was concatenated with the following term without parentheses, multiplication operator, or even a space.  I see no reason that should be regarded as any more correct than writing (1/2)5 as 1/25.  I could see reasonable arguments for saying that 1/2x is not a correct way of writing 1/(2x), but I see none for regarding it as a correct way of writing (1/2)x.  IMHO, parentheses around a division expression should be considered mandatory whenever it will be concatenated with the following expression.  While writing (1/x)(y+z) as...

Comment: ...1/x(y+z) wouldn't be quite as unreasonable as writing (1/2x) as 1/2x, I would still regard it as, at best, inferior notation, *regardless of what it is supposed to mean*.  IMHO, it would more likely occur as a result of transcribing the *stacked* fraction dividing x(y+z) into 1, but might also occur as a result of transcribing the entirely proper concatenation of the *stacked* fraction 1/x with the expression (y+z).

Answer (score 8):

I am with you on this one. I feel like concatenation (implied multiplication) is of higher precedence than explicit division. For me $8:2x$ means "8 divided by 2 x'es" - $8:(2x)$ not $4x$. Replacing $x$ with $(2+2)$ shouldn't change anything.

But the formal answer is that it's undefined. There is no C for concatenation in PEMDAS. For me it should be PECMDAS.

> People in comments are suggesting *juxtaposition* (positioning side by side) instead of *concatenation* (joining strings together). PEJMDAS then. IMO both terms are very similar, but *juxtaposition* is indeed more common in the math world.

I definitely don't agree that concatenation should be resolved to multiplication before applying PEMDAS. By such logic you could also start with resolving E and get $8:2^2=8:2×2=8$ which is wrong. You are supposed to apply PEMDAS before resolving notation otherwise you are mixing order.

A final but necessary note- just never write division inline, it's too ambiguous unless you divide by one term only at the very end of line. I always either divide under the bar or for simple cases just multiply by the inverse.

EDIT: Rethinking again I am convincing myself even more that this is not and shouldn't be answerable in terms of PEMDAS. PEMDAS is a tool to resolve sequence of operations out of a notation. If you add notation that is neither of PEMDAS, there is no answer. Doesn't even matter if it's concatenation, derivative, logarithm, applying function... Neither of that is answered by PEMDAS.

Comment: Sorry for the repetitive comment with the other thread, I agree that saying it is undefined is an arguably reasonable stance. I disagree however with the "By that logic", since E  has higher precedence the $2^2$ must be replaced by $(2 \times 2)$, and the problem goes away. The implied addition of those parenthesis is the very point of the precedence rule.

Comment: @quid just like we could replace $ab$ with $(a \times b)$ if we agreed on precedence of that. And the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank-you. That was the word (concatenation) I was looking for. Right or wrong, at least I can now verbalize what my reasoning was.

Comment: Correct. Expressions such as $1/2x$ and $1/2\pi$ are written with the intention that implicit multiplication be given precedence over division.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I think the term is juxtaposition, not concatenation. Concatenating $12$ and $34$ would yield $1234$.

Comment: Yes, and if wishes were horses beggars would ride. :-)  My point is precisely that no one did agree on that. If your point is that we should agree on that, that's fine. It does not alter the fact that to the best of my knowledge there is no such convention firmly established. // @RosieF : sometimes yes. But, that's  not exactly the same, and mostly comes from a time when fractions where difficult to typeset. Mostly it's also somewhat sloppy. One might also writ $\sin n\pi x$ and it would be completely clear what is meant.

Comment: @Namaste: JoeTaxpayer was explicitely talking about the word "concatenation", I merely mentioned the existence of another word which might be more suitable. No need to try to make your point in yet another comment.

Comment: @Namaste the post owner with the first part, the user notified with the second.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I agree with Eric that "juxtaposition" is the correct term (not "concatenation"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juxtaposition#Mathematics

Comment: I learned Juxtaposition in concert with distribution.  As Distribution happens prior to the P in PEMDAS it can with in both PEMDAS and PEJMDAS, but also covered implied multiplication between variables.  However Regardless of Juxtaposition, distribution shows that you will be doing multiplication BEFORE PEMDAS is applied.  Just as with Juxtaposition.

Answer (score 7):

> Now, my question - for those who agree with me, what is it about
>   PEMDAS that misses this issue, that the number right before the
>   parentheses multiplies the contents with a higher priority than the
>   division to its left? How do we address that priority?

The conventional order-of-operations in textbook math (or any math) simply don't prioritize juxtaposed multiplication over other types of multiplication. The ordering is simply (elementary operations only):

1. Exponents and radicals
2. Multiplication and division
3. Addition and subtraction

Each stage associates left-to-right, and grouping symbols (parentheses) always prioritize whatever's inside them. One can also observe all kind of useful symmetries built in this list: Operations are in pairs, with inverses together on each line (really two sides of the same coin in each case). Operations on same-base-powers downshift one place in all cases (to exponentiate powers, multiply the exponents; to multiply powers, add the exponents, etc.). Operations distribute over any operation on line lower. Etc., etc. [See more.](http://www.madmath.com/2012/07/power-rules.html)

If this is the agreed-upon ordering, then the value of the expression in the OP is 16.

Now let's say that we really, really want the value to be 1 instead. In this case we must add the extra, perceived (by the OP) rule that juxtaposed multiplication should come before other types of multiplying/division. We must insert a new stage:

1. Exponents and radicals
2. Juxtaposed multiplications
3. Other multiplications and division
4. Addition and subtraction

With that, the result produced in the OP is 1. But note that all the previous symmetries are destroyed! We no longer dependably (and memorably) have two operations on each line, inverses are not entirely collected on one line, the "shift down one place" shortcut for operations on same-base powers is gone, etc.

So: you can design a rule which forces juxtaposed multiplications to happen at a special earlier stage. *But do you really want to destroy all the associated symmetries for that?*

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here : couldn't you add functions in the second line to get two "operations" again on each line? f(2x) and 2(2x) with the same priority?

Comment: @EricDuminil: They wouldn't be inverses. And I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want functions below exponents; e.g., f(3)^2 becomes nonsensical. Plus all the other symmetries are still broken.

Comment: If your argument were valid, it would mean that $a/bc$ means $(a/b)c$, i.e. $ac/b$. Is this what you see in mathematical texts? Because I don't. I see e.g. $1/2x$ used to mean $1/(2x)$, not $(1/2)x$. You argue against your second order (the one with juxtaposition listed 2nd in a list of 4) but IME that is the order that mathematical writers actually use.

Comment: @RosieF: I have absolutely never seen that in my entire library of mathematical texts. Like other people answering here, I agree that it would be a terrible piece of writing to do so. Can you provide an example from a mathematical text where that occurs? I'm skeptical.

Comment: I think the question regarding $/$ came up maybe on this site or some other SEsite at some point. It seems that in some circles there indeed was the convention that  $some / thing$ would mean $\frac{some}{thing}$ back in the day when fraction where hard to typeset. Somebody then even mention an exact convention maybe it was until the next $+,-,=$ or even next $=$. That said I think it's a bit tangential to the question at hand.   cc @RosieF

Comment: @quid: I've never seen it, and I have a college algebra book from 1923/1933 that I consult regularly. I'll remain skeptical (esp. the claim for math textbooks) until someone like Rosie can provide one or more real examples.

Comment: The context was almost certainly  not math textbooks, I think  engineering or something like that was mentioned.

Comment: @quid you are right about $some/thing$. [Here's](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3523/1/FEYpr49c.pdf) a famous Feynman's paper and, among simpler $e^2/\pi i$, it even contains $(p_1+m/2m)$ in (29) which means $\frac {p_1+m}{2m}$. That's a bit extreme but any physicist would take $/2x$ to mean $/(2x)$.

Answer (score 5):

> My disagreement lies in the dismissal of the parentheses, as my explanation would be that
>
> $8÷2(x+x)$ would, as a first step, simplify to
>
> $8÷2(2x)$ and then
>
> $8÷4x$

It seems to me that you are:

1. ignoring the Left To Right rule,
2. not making the implied multiplication between $2$ and $(2+2)$

Comment: No, I *want* to make that multiplication, 2(2+2), first. That's why I got 1. And yes, I was giving that preference over left to right. Džuris offered the word I was looking for, "concatenation", which, whether my conclusion was correct or not, at least offered the vocabulary for what I was trying to express.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer you might wish to do it, and you might be taught so at school. But there are no such mathematical operations as "juxtaposition" or "implicit multiplication".

Comment: @Gnudiff There are no such mathematical operations as "parentheses" or "brackets" either. This is not a story about mathematical operations but about notation - the tools to convey intended order of operations. And juxtaposition is a notational tool, just one that is not strictly defined in PEMDAS.

Answer (score 5):

This would be better as a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation. Daniel R. Collins asked for an example of a mathematical text writing something like $a/bc$ to mean $a/(bc)$, and it might be useful as a counterexample to the strong claims that a mathematician would *never* write such a thing.

On page 2 of *Geometry Revisited* by Coxeter and Greitzer, in the context of the Law of Sines, they write that $\sin A=a/2R$, where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle $ABC$. On the next page, they ask the reader to prove that the area of said triangle is $abc/4R$.

So examples in pure math books by well-known mathematicians can be found, but the only reason I could easily point to this example is because I think it's the only one I've personally seen and I remember noticing the ambiguity right away.

edit: I just happened to see the following expression on page 98 of *Basic Probability Theory* by Robert Ash (free online):

$$\frac{[6!/j!k!(6-j-k)!](1/6)^{j+k}(4/6)^{6-j-k}}{[6!k!(6-k)!](1/6)^k(5/6)^{6-k}}$$

But since both numerator and denominator were written in a cleaner way right before this, and since there is only one sensible interpretation in the context of the problem, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Indeed, I've seen a few such things, and/but the stuff in front (with the early division) is somehow a "coefficient" of the other part "$R$" in your example. Also, this broaches the possibility of disambiguating by using "units"... so in engineering, physics, chemistry contexts a good fraction of the ambiguity is removed.

Comment: Thanks for that example. Admitting that they have a number of other nonstandard typography issues on just the first few pages; e.g., they use $XY$ as the length of line segment from point $X$ to $Y$, they omit the words "show" or "prove" in all exercises for brevity, etc.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins "...they use XY as the length of line segment from point X to Y." This has been my standard naming practice. Is this nonstandard?

Comment: @NickC: I would have thought $XY$ is the line segment and $|XY|$ or something the length. Coxeter/Greitzer themselves note they're using $XY$ because of a typographical limitation.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I always used $XY $ for the length, and $\overline {XY} $ for the segment itself, along the lines (no pun intended) of: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the cases where a linguist has to admit that we don't actually *make* the rules for a language.  We discover them, and codify them.  And there's always exceptions [like](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079ZYZVBM)

> **I before E**
>   Except when your foreign neighbor Keith receives eight beige counterfeit sleighs from feisty caffeinated weightlifters

English is *weird*.

PEMDAS is a linguistic rule in the same vein.  There is no worldwide governing board that defines the typography and interpretation for these equations.  It's just how we got used to communicating with one another.  If you don't use PEMDAS, you increase the likelihood of miscommunication.

However, when it comes to multiplication after a division, in particular multiplication with an elided operator there are dialectical disagreements about the meaning.  Remember, all of these rules are designed to make communication easier.  Communication is easier without all those parentheses in the way, so if there is indeed an unambiguous way of parsing expressions without adding parentheses, we like to do so.  That's why we have PEMDAS in the first place.  It got rid of the need to write (2*x) + (3*y) = 0.

So what about 1/xy?  There's an easier way to write (1/x)*y, mainly y/x, so that strongly suggests that the only reason one would write in this order is to imply 1/(x*y). But then what about 2/3x?  That could be 2/(3x) or (2/3)x.  Writing fractions in front of a variable is an awfully common thing to do, so we typically don't burden it with extra parenthesis.  Some prefer to write that case as 2/3*x.

Elided operators seem to bind "tighter" than others, but not everyone agrees on this.  This tends to be the fundamental problem with this entire class of "trick" questions.  Most are very comfortable with agreeing upon $8\div 4\times x$, but get less comfortable with $8\div 4x$.  Situations like $\frac{1}{2x}$ show up often enough to want to be able to phrase them with a short parentheses-free notation.  Whether this want is strong enough to change your interpretation is up to you.

So what's the correct value of $8\div 2(2+2)$?  The correct value is a friend who's trying to be mean using ambiguous syntax's to look smart.  Alternatively, the correct answer is to go back to whoever wrote it and ask them to fix the ambiguous phrasing.

Answer (score 4):

I think (other than the fact that it's pretty much a deliberately ambiguous question) the thing that is missing is the concept of things being single terms, which ought to be evaluated first.

I would interpret the expression as 1, because I'd consider 2(2 + 2) to be a single term that should be evaluated first before the answer is substituted back into the rest of the expression. If it had been written with a multiplication sign it wouldn't be a single term, so the answer would end up being 16. Similar to how 1 ÷ 2 would be treated differently to 1/2.

This can also be expressed as implicit operations having higher priority than explicit ones.

(I'm based in the UK, so likely to have come from a different perspective - I was certainly taught, when we got that far, that implicit had priority and thus you should treat terms as single items)

Comment: This is very interesting, it appears that the concept of "single term", which only appears as a separate math article in Simple English Wikipedia, is something coined specifically for teaching elementary math. It might be responsible for a lot of confusion, because it appears to explicitly apply to polynomials. However, expression 8/2(2+2) is *not* a polynomial, since it contains division, therefore concept of *single term*  doesn't seem to be applicable here.

Comment: @Namaste I actually found "single term" with some difficulty: it appears to be some sort of elementary math education definition, apparently in the US(?) http://www.whatcom.edu/home/showdocument?id=1772

Comment: @Namaste, "Term" is a phrase that you wouldn't argue about if any of those numbers was replaced by a variable, it clearly applies to constant terms in an expression which also contains a variable, and it is a natural use that I have heard frequently in my schooling to also apply it to elements within an expression such as this one in the obvious manner, as a shorthand for talking about groupings via implicit operations vs explicit operations. Maybe that's not common wording worldwide.

Comment: Also, "single term" even in full on algebra certainly includes "cx^p" for any value of c and p (constant, or variable, and I'm including e.g. p=1/2 here), trying to restrict to saying "x" otherwise it's not a single term is being deliberately disingenuous.

Comment: @Namaste You seem to have ignored the concept of implicit vs explicit operations.

Answer (score 3):

> The third option is also fine, that such a set of numbers and symbols is ambiguous, and a second set of parentheses is required for clarification.

I'm going to suggest a variant of this which you might consider a fourth option: The $\div$ operator is at best confusing if not ambiguous, and should not be used. For a long time I actually thought it was a nelogism based on a fraction bar and placeholder dots, and derided it on that too, but apparently it does have much deeper history. Still, it's not used whatsoever by working mathematicians, engineers, physicists, etc. **for very good reason**. The lesson here, in a math-education context, is that it shouldn't be used. Full fraction bars for division make it entirely unambiguous, and use of $/$ is almost universally interpreted as binding looser than implicit multiplication (but should still probably be avoided in ambiguous contexts).

Beyond that, this question makes great lesson for students in the potential ambiguity of notation, disagreements about meaning, and importance of **defining** any notation you want to use for which there is not an obvious agreed-upon meaning.

Comment: For what "very good" reason is the obelus not used? In programming, it's a lot harder typing Alt+246 than hitting the forward slash, and in hand-written stuff it's easier and clearer to draw the numerator over the denominator. But I use the obelus symbol quite frequently in non-programming contexts (and in comments in code) because it's less confusing than a forward slash. Unless I feel like going through the trouble of formatting a proper fraction slash, MathJax, etc. I also never assume 1/2X means 1÷(2X), and write (1/2)X, ½X, 1/2 X, or ½ X to be clear in that context.

Answer (score 3):

In the order of operations, one multiplication does not take precedence over another; all multiplications and divisions are performed from left to right.  A so-called "concatenation" with parentheses a(b) has the exact same meaning as "a times b".  The parenthesis operation only takes precedence over other operations to evaluate what is inside.  After that, it becomes an M, and the P is done.

It is very unfortunate that Casio wasn't competent enough to parse an unambiguous context-free grammar correctly in one of their models.  That model should be recalled, because it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the difficulty is that order of operations is taught wrong.

The basic rule of order of operations is this:

"Operations are performed from left to right *unless*..."

The first *unless* is the existence of parentheses.

Now here's where another factor (pun unintentional) comes into play:  we write in lines.  Because of that, something has to come first as we read.

What we should say is that multiplication and division are *coprecedent*:  neither takes place before the other, at which point, the "left to right *unless*" comes into play.

So in $8 \div 2 \times 4$, we do the $8 \div 2$ first, getting $4$, then evaluating $4 \times 4$, getting $16$.

Unfortunately, when we reduce order of operations to an acronym, we lump M and D into the same word, and since it's harder to pronounce PEDMAS, we say PEMDAS.

(A and S have the same coprecedence relationship:  $8 - 3 + 5 = 10$, not 0)

Here's a more in-depth overview of order of operations:

https://youtu.be/A3o555TzKb0?list=PLKXdxQAT3tCtutiLV9QYh_2lDuNphhhCP

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought comments would suffice, instead of an answer, because there have been a couple good answers already.

However, it appears that there are a number of issues at hand, some of them regarding math education rather than mathematical notation.

Nevertheless, let me first make a couple notes about notation though, as part of the subject.

- I would like to note, that the *original question could only arise in "paper" maths, which has the wonderful opportunity of its notation being able to be interpreted differently*.

In computer programming, math expressions usually are not ambiguous at all. Every math expression is calculated the same way in the same programming language, and writing it one way you can only get one and the same answer with respect to operation precedence.

The order of precedence is, as @Daniel-R-Collins wrote:

1. all operations calculated started from left-to-right, subject to below precedence in order:
2. operations within parenthesis taken as separate list of operations and calculated first, using this same set of rules.
3. exponentiation (and some other operations less common in school equations, such as modulus)
4. multiplication/division (usually denoted by "*" and "/" signs)
5. addition/subtraction

So, if you wanted 8÷2(2+2) to mean 16, you'd write it: `8/2*(2+2)` = 16 (1)

If you wanted it to mean 1, you'd have to write: `8/(2*(2+2))` = 1 (2)

Computers don't care what you want. If you wrote (1), you'd always get 16, regardless of what you wanted [Note that there exist programming languages which do use eg. postfix notation for mathematical operations, such as [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), which would write the above as:  `8 2 / 2 2 + *` to get 16, and `8 2 2 2 + * /` to get 1.]

Nevertheless **I do not know any general purpose programming language, in which 8/2*(2+2) would be 1**. So at least this front has come to an agreement on the subject.

- Next, as I wrote in comments already, there are five mathematical operations + parenthesis, which are described by the OP's PEMDAS rules. Five. **There is no such mathematical operation as "implicit multiplication". The only thing there is, is an implied multiplication *_sign_* when writing mathematical equations on paper.**

It can also be reasonably inferred, how this could have come about. Writing equations **on paper** you would like to get rid of ·, which is a pesky little symbol that is taking space, seems to be more frequent than division, and is usually also tightly coupled to the expression, so it would frequently *be* first in priority of expression. Also, on paper you do have the large horizontal bar for all your division needs, so you could simply stretch a luxurious $\frac{8}{2(2+2)}$ over your implied multiplication and avoid any confusion whatsoever.

As a rule of thumb, if you turn something implicit into explicit, it should show what it was about. If you do not construct any imaginary "implied multiplication", but take the "implicit multiplication" to simply mean "implicit multiplication *sign*", then what you get left from 8÷2(2+2) is exactly 8÷2·(2+2).

- Now we have come to the part of the matter, which keeps popping up in many comments. Forget about implicit multiplication, what about the division sign?

As I read that in engineering (at least in some parts of the world), it is frequently expected that `1/something` implies `1/(something)`, using slash sign as a fraction bar. While I can't argue for or against it in particular field, I would be surprised if it didn't *only* work for values, the correct form of which were *expected to be known*. If you know that the modulating signal frequency in Hertz is equal to $$\frac{\omega_m}{2\pi}$$ then it is expected that you could often write it as ωm/2π, and indeed it seems that people do.

However, this agains seems to work in particular jargon of the field and **on paper**. You can't willy nilly put long or short fraction bars when writing computer programs, therefore even engineers will have to use computer notation, when dealing with programming. Computer notation, again, to avoid ambiguity, deals with the matter simply by having a division sign that follows the same above listed PEMDAS rules. If you want to write $\frac{1/2\pi}{3+x}$ on computer, you have to write `1/(2*pi)/(3+x)`. No shortcuts.

All of this leads me to the following conclusions:

1. The way to calculate expressions such as 8/2(2+2) will feel more "natural" depending on how you were taught. In addition, in some fields, it is more expected to for division signs in electronic texts to be meant as long fraction bars on paper.
2. As described here and in @Daniel's answer it might be argued that it is more correct to use the form where 8/2(2+2)=16, simply because there are no no hidden expectations such as "implicit multiplication" and "my division signs are in fact long fraction bars".
3. I would be surprised if much of the world didn't expect their equations the 8/2(2+2)=16 way. The whole of the former USSR, for example, where nobody ever heard of implicit multiplication or fraction bars [we used ":" as division sign in notation and used parenthesis a lot more than fraction bars. Starting with some 5th grade it was more  frequent to see school examples as $15:(3+3)$ rather than $\frac{15}{3+3}$ ]
4. Nevertheless, when it comes to math **education**, the considerations should probably include:

   - whatever is *taught* to people, they must be made *aware* of the possibilities of different interpretation to notations;
   - especially if they are taught that 8/2(2+2)=1 , they should be made aware that no computers will understand it this way, because exposure to computers is ubiquitous nowadays (I am not even talking programming, try doing this in Excel);
   - whatever is taught to people in school will probably need to be in line with the *existing textbooks*.

Comment: You make some good points, e.g. with engineering. But for many programming languages (e.g. Ruby/Python/Java/...), it's not even allowed to write `8/2(2+2)` so I'm not really sure what your argument is. Juxtaposition simply isn't considered in those programming languages because `f(x)` could mean `f` times `x` or `f` function evaluated at `x`. OP's question is about juxtaposition.

Comment: @EricDuminil No programming language I know of, allows you to omit multiplication sign. It is an indirect confirmation of the fact that when you write 2(2+2) you are *not* creating any special new operations [such as some strange implicit multiplication with higher priority than the rest of ops], but just using a shorthand, and 2(2+2)= 2*(2+2) which follows the normal rules as if it was written in full.

Comment: `No programming language I know of, allows you to omit multiplication sign.` so why are you talking about programming languages in a question which resolves around the omission of the multiplication sign? `It is an indirect confirmation`. No, that's just confirmation bias from your part. I explained why juxtaposition cannot be included in programming languages in my previous comment. Otherwise, should `abc` be `a*b*c` or `a*bc` or just the `abc` variable? The rest of the answer is really good BTW.

Comment: @EricDuminil (1) References to programming languages are relevant, because programming languages have to implement math correctly to be useful, and people have to frequently use computers [as I wrote, not only programming, but also Excel], so they should know what the computer expects. Your mileage may vary, but at least for myself, I see the connection.

Comment: (2) Juxtaposition is very strange term, which I only encounter when speaking about it here and (it seems) only with certain Anglo-Saxon methods of teaching maths. Insofar as it is defined in Wikipedia, it only refers to the fact of ability to omit sign of operation, nothing about changing operation precedence depending on proximity.
As a counter question,as we know we can express any term of equation with a variable. Let's say a=8, b=2 and c=2+2 in the OP's example. How would you write the equation (in computer notation, let's say) and what should be the result?

Comment: The former USSR hadn't heard of fraction bars and implicit multiplication? Is that a joke? Have you read any article by Soviet scientists? 
[Here](https://ftfsite.ru/wp-content/files/landau_statfiz_4.2.pdf) is one of the Landau's books. It's full of implied multiplication and fraction bars and doesn't contain $:$ or $\div$ at all. Footnote on page 28 contains $~\hbar / mL^2$ which means $~\hbar/(mL^2)$.
It is not some Anglo-Saxon notation, it's just how people (outside secondary school) write math.

Comment: @Džuris Exactly. I thought we were talking about PEMDAS, which in fact *is* inside secondary school (at least the way secondary school was defined in the USSR at the time I was learning in it). Nowhere in my post I have suggestied USSR didn't have fraction bars in general We *are* talking math education, elementary level, as far as I understand.

Comment: As an additional example from engineering, cost of electricity is often written in $€/\textrm{MWh}$. Now, should it be parsed as $\frac{€}{\textrm{MWh}}$ or $\frac{€h}{\textrm{MW}}$?